# Enumerate list flush with margin

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

As seen below, I am trying to create a simple boxed enumerate list with the items in the margin.

[image]

I have two problems with the code below

- *Main problem:* the enumerate list is *slightly* off-center, is there some simple fix for this?
- *Minor problem:* Can I use the `\item[123]` without having to use `\fbox` every time?

.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

    \newlist{problem}{enumerate}{1}
    \setlist[problem, 1]{
      leftmargin=*,
      labelindent=-\labelwidth,
      label=\protect\fbox{\arabic*},
      resume=problem%
    }

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem}

\lipsum[75]

\begin{problem}
    \item \lipsum[66]
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
    \item[\fbox{123}] \lipsum[5]
\end{problem}

\lipsum[66]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `leftmargin=0pt`. The `showframe` is for checking of alignment only.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlist{problem}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[problem, 1]{
  leftmargin=0pt,
  label={\fbox{{\arabic*}}},
  labelindent=-\labelwidth,
  resume=problem%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem}

\lipsum[75]

\begin{problem}
    \item \lipsum[66]
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}[start=123]
\item \lipsum[5]
\end{problem}


\lipsum[66]

\end{document}
```

[image]